# Proca field in the ultra-relativistic limit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, mass, field-theory, dimensional-analysis

I was recently asked by a professor of mine to show that in the ultra-relativistic regime a Proca field has mass dimension of 2 instead of 1 (in $d=4$). As a hint, I was advised to look at the Proca propagator and work in the ultra-relativistic regime.

I know that the Proca propagator reads:
$$\Pi_{\mu\nu}(k)=\frac{i}{k^2-M^2}\left[-\eta^{\mu\nu}+\frac{k_\mu k_\nu}{M^2}\right]\approx\frac{i}{k^2}\left[\frac{k_\mu k_\nu}{M^2}\right]$$

where in the last step I applied the UR regime for the prefactor and neglected the $\eta$ because only the longitudinal polarization survives.

Now comes the tricky part. I know that a generic propagator $\Pi_{\mu\nu}$ in the momentum space can be written as the inverse of an invertible operator $M^{\mu\nu}$ such that the action reads:

$$ S=-\frac{1}{2}\int d^4k A_\mu(k)M^{\mu\nu}A_\nu(-k). $$
I would like to adress this problem by doing the inverse of such propagator in the UR regime to recover a lagrangian density wich then contains a vector field with mass dimension 2. I therefore write
$$M^{\mu\nu}=c_1\eta^{\mu\nu}+c_2k^\mu k^\nu$$
and impose the condition $M^{\mu\nu}\Pi_{\nu\rho}=\delta^\mu_\rho$. So far so good, but then I come to a point where I can't get around, namely:
$$c_1k^\mu k_\rho+c_2k^2k^\mu k_\rho+i\delta^\mu_\rho k^2M^2=0.$$
I feel I am missing something, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: As far as I'm aware propagators are generally not invertible, they're projection matrices which remove non-physical modes. For example, your $\Pi$ at the top has $k$ in its nullspace. Maybe you need to add a term to the right hand side of $M^{\mu\nu}\Pi_{\nu\rho}=\delta^\mu_\rho$ to make it rank 3.